# Console IO for Java applet

Tags: java

I have a console based (`System.in` and `System.out` based) Java standalone application. I am trying to convert it into an applet. But the problem is that there is no console in Java applet! In other words, when I write to system output it is not displayed to the user and similarly I am unable to get input from user in absence of a console.

I know that a console lookalike can be done using `TextArea` and `KeyListener`, but for that I would need two different components, one for input and one for output. I want the input and output to go into the same component. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, it's Java and not JAVA (not an acronym).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But there is a standard console for Java applets :)

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/console.html

Joking aside, there does seem to be some [console code](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes2/source/ConsoleApplet.java) on this site: http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes2/source/index.html. Apparently you can just extend this class and it'll give you a console in your applet. However, you may need to redirect System.out (standard output), System.err (error output) and System.in (input) into the console. That doesn't seem to be implemented but could be blocked in applets by the SecurityManager.

Comment: about the first part: You can't be serious. That's a debug component, not something that's part of your app's UI

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `JTextArea` editable, you can then listen for `DocumentEvent`s that indicate when a user has entered text.

That said, and not knowing anything about your applet, it's generally nicer from a UI perspective if the user does not have to type into a console. Consider breaking the input into distinct fields, with a clear transition from input to execution to output.

Comment: How can I disable backspace and delete in JTextArea, for the output I am giving while enabling it for the input user is giving (as happens in a console window)?

Comment: Is it really important to do that? If it is, then you can reject document changes (I can't remember how to do this, but it's covered in the Swing tutorial). However, why not just keep track of the last position in the document and only accept user input after that position?

Answer (score 0):

The way I always run a console based Java program without downloading anything is running over to the trust command prompt terminal.

> 1. Click windows button + r (or open file explorer or program search)
> 2. Next, type "cmd" into the search box and hit enter.
> 3. Now, in the command prompt terminal, type `java -jar xx.jar` without quotes and replacing xx with the program name.

That's it! It's as simple as that! If you would like to make a file that you click on that automatically runs your Java application, continue with these steps:

> 1. Make a new text document where you want your start program file to be.
> 2. In the text document, type:
>
> `@echo off`
>
> `start java -jar xx.jar`
>
> `exit`
>
> 3. Save the file as a .bat file.

That is how you make a batch file to run your Java application!